# Jupyter Notebook ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For some background, I read a csv file for my dataset and isolated some of the data using:

```
isolated = diff['2012-09-28' <= pd.to_datetime(diff['start_date'])]
isolated
```

The code worked well until I code this:

```
counter = 0
xlim = []
current = ''
for date in isolated['start_date']:
    if date in debates and current != date:
        xlim.append(counter)
        current = date
    counter += 1

x_min = min(xlim)
x_max = max(xlim)
print(str(x_min) +" - " + str(x_max))
xlim.append(max(xlim)-5)
print(xlim)
```

It's supposed to return

```
37 - 65
[37, 55, 65, 60]
diff.plot('Start Date','Difference',figsize=(12,4), marker='o', linestyle='-',color='blue',xlim=(, x_max))
```

I'm going to use it for plotting.

Comment: That means `xlim` is empty. That means that you never put anything into `xlim`. That means `date in debates and current != date` is never `True`. Now you can debug it further as you have more information on these variables

Answer (score 0):

```py
min([])
```

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

So, error is clear. Your line `x_min = min(xlim)` is computing `min([])`. Or said otherwise `xlim` is empty.

Your real problem is to understand why it is. That we can't say, it is in your data.